# How to configure inverse and forward search in Kile (LaTeX editor)

Tags: kde, latex, kile

That is it. There is not much to that question.

Inverse and forward search is basically to be able to do some kind of Ctrl+Click in a line of the *.tex file, and automatically be sent to the PDF viewer to that exact line, and the opposite operation.

I am using the embedded viewer, doing the standard QuickBuild.

Comment: Please edit to tell us what inverse search is. Is it reverse search? And in what way you would like to configure it?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor done.